# VBA Error 13 (Type Mismatch) when trying to add items to Collection

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, collections

I have 2 arrays taken from two ranges containing names. I want to create a 3rd array with ONLY the names in array 1 that are not in array 2. However there's a **mismatch type error** when trying to add values to a **collection**.

This is the whole code:

```
Sub CrearArreglos()

'**Array2**
Dim Array2() As Variant 
Dim iCountLI As Long 
Dim iElementLI As Long 

If IsEmpty(Range("B3").Value) = True Then
      ReDim Array2(0, 0)
Else
      iCountLI = (Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row) - 2
      iCountLI = (Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row) - 2 
      ReDim Array2(iCountLI) 

      For iElementLI = 1 To iCountLI 
      Array2(iElementLI - 1) = Cells(iElementLI + 2, 2).Value 
      Next iElementLI
      
End If

'**Array 1:**
Dim Array1() As Variant 
Dim iElementLC As Long

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Array1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BD4:BD10").Value 

Dim v3 As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
Dim i As Long

'**Extracting values from Array 1 that are not contained in Array 2**
Set coll = New Collection

For i = LBound(Array1, 1) To UBound(Array1, 1)
    If Array1(i, 1) <> 0 Then
'**This line below displays error 13 ↓
    coll.Add Array1(i, 1), Array1(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

For i = LBound(Array2, 1) To UBound(Array2, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Add Array2(i, 1), Array2(i, 1) 
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        coll.Remove Array2(i, 1)
    End If
    If coll.exists(Array2(i, 1)) Then
        coll.Remove Array2(i, 1)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i


ReDim v3(0 To (coll.Count) - 1)

'Adds collection items to a new array:
For i = LBound(v3) To UBound(v3)
    v3(i) = coll(i + 1) 
    Debug.Print v3(i)
Next i
```

So this is the line where error 13 is displayed. If I remove the second "Array1(i, 1)", it runs fine but it only saves all values from Array1 and it seems to ignore the rest of the code and the conditions)

```
coll.Add Array1(i, 1), Array1(i, 1)
```

Oddly enough, this code has always worked **perfectly** in the past when having both ranges in the same sheet. This time I'm taking the ranges from different sheets. I don´t know if that's the issue, although it doesn't make sense for me.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might get that error if one of the values is empty (which is not the same as 0)

Comment: the second argument is the optional key and must be a string.

Comment: Your code can never have run perfectly because the Collection object does not have an .Exists method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the same thing as you intend, and with good performance:

```vb
Sub CrearArreglos()

    Dim Array1, col As New Collection, i As Long, rng2 As Range, arrOut, v
    
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        Set rng2 = .Range("B3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Array1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BD4:BD10").Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(Array1, 1)
        v = Array1(i, 1)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then 'anything to check?
            'this check is faster against a range...
            If IsError(Application.Match(v, rng2, 0)) Then col.Add v
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReDim arrOut(0 To col.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        arrOut(i - 1) = col(i)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked great and it looks way cleaner!! Thank you so much!!